# functions and if statements

Tags: php

Does anyone know how I could echo rconresults and if its not rconresults to call rconresults1 or rconresults2? The only one that works at the moment is echo rconresults(); function at the bottom, I am new to this :P

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
include("../classes/functions2.php");
include("../classes/functions.php");
require '../classes/q3status.php';
require '../classes/q3rcon.php';
include("rconform.php");
include("rconresults.php");
include("rconresults1.php");
include("rconresults2.php");
$theme = $_COOKIE['currenttheme'];?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../templates/$theme/style.css\" media=\"screen\" />"; ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<div align='center'>";
echo rconform();
echo '<br><a href="javascript:self.close()">close window</a>';
echo "</div>";
echo rconresults();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Rconresults calls this file and I have 3 with different requests

```
   <?php
    function rconresults() {
include "../classes/config_inc.php";
$server3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['rconserver']);
$say = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['say']);
echo "<div align='center'>";
if ($server3 != "") {
$server3 = addslashes($server3);
mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$db_database") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("select * from {$db_prefix}_servers where `id`='{$server3}'");
if (!$result) {
    die("No Server Available with id {$server3}");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

// store the record of the "example" table into $row
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
// Print out the contents of the entry 

$r = new q3rcon($row['ip'], $row['port'], $row['rconpass']);
$data = explode(" ", $say);
if ($data[0] == "clientkick" && count($data) > 2) {
    $data = explode(" ", $say, 3);
    $r->send_command("".$data[0]." ".$data[1]." \"".$data[2]."\"");
} else {
    $r->send_command("say " . $say);
}
$out = $r->get_response();

$out2 = explode("\n", $out);
echo "<table class='container9'><tr><td>";
if ($out == '') {
    echo "Command Sent!";
}
foreach($out2 as $line) {
    if ($line != '') {
        echo "".strip_gtlt(strip_colors($line))."<br>";
    }
}
echo "</td></tr></table>";
}
echo "</div>";
    }
    ?>
```

I think you mean this? When you click the button then it restarts the map?

```
<?php
function rconform()
{
include("../classes/config_inc.php");
echo "<form method='post' action=''><table class='container8'><tr><td><table width='300'>";
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><div align='center'><font size='4'><strong>Run RCON Command</strong></font></div></td></tr><tr><td><div align='right'>Server:</div></td><td><div align='left'>";
echo "<select name='rconserver'><option selected='selected'>Select</option>";
mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$db_database") or die(mysql_error());
$sql="SELECT * FROM `".$db_prefix."_servers` where `Status`='Online' order by `order` ASC";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$svname = $data['name'];
$svname = stripslashes($svname);
$svid = $data['id'];
if ($svname == $server3) {
$selected = "selected=\"$svname\"";
} else {
$selected = "";
}
echo "<option value =\"$svid\" $selected>$svname</option>";
} 
echo "</select></div></td></tr><tr><td><div align='right'>Console:</div></td><td><div align='left'><input type='text' placeholder='Say something..' name='say'></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'><div align='center'><input type='submit' value='Execute'></div></td></tr></td></tr></form>";
echo "</select></div></td></tr><tr><td><div align='right'>Change Map:</div></td><td><div align='left'><input type='text' placeholder='mp_harbor' name='map'></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'><div align='center'><input type='submit' value='Execute'></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></form>";
echo "</select></div></td></tr><tr><td><div align='right'><input type='submit' value='Restart Map' name='map_restart'></div></td></tr>
  </tr>
</table></td></tr></table>
</form>";

}

?>
```

Comment: What does `rconresults()` return? Something that can be interpreted as false in case you want to try rconresults1 or rconresults2?

Comment: I updated the post to show what rconresults does :)

Comment: "...if rconrsults is called..." That helps, how is reconresults called? Is there user input or a PHP variable that has that information?

Comment: I updated the code again do you mean the buttons at the bottom? sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what rconresults is returning.

If it's a boolean condition, the code below will run rconresults if it's true, and run rconresults2 if it's false.

It will all depend on the condition.

```
if ( $_REQUEST['option'] == "rconresults2" ) {
    echo rconresults2();
} else {
    echo rconresults();
}
```

Update.

Comment: When i try this code it calls both rconresults and reconresult2 at the same time?

Comment: I know because rconresults() is not retuning anything. What's the condition for each function to run?

Comment: Check the new condition I added. You can replace the request variable for whatever variable you want. You still didn't mention what request will be required to call each function.

Comment: This looks like the solution. Put this in the first file you posted, replace `rconresults();` with this and enter the appropriate variable. (I'm still not sure what that is.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused about how includes work. It seems that you want something like this:

```
if (some condition { 

   include("rconform.php");

} else if (some other condition) { 

   include("rconresults.php");

} else if ( a different condition) {

    include("rconresults1.php");

} else {
    include("rconresults2.php");
}
```

But you didn’t say what the conditional was. If you could tell us a bit more about what you want to accomplish, we could provide some guidance.

Comment: Hi i am trying to get it to return rconresults if rconrsults is called or rconresults2 if thats called and so on :)